# formato fecha a string en java con apache desde excel

Tags: java, apache, excel

Tengo que leer el formato de una celda con fecha a String, funciona bien pero el año sale extraño, adjunto parte del código y lo que muestra:

```
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
           String  s =  sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());

                   if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                       System.out.print(s);
            }
           System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());         
                    break;
```

Muestra lo siguiente : si mi fecha es: `01/03/1994`
por pantalla sale: `01/03/199434394.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es debido a que justo después de la fecha imprimes el *valor numérico* de la celda, y en Excel las fechas se representan como números de coma flotante.

Creo que así lo verás más claro:

```
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
    if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String  s =  sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
        System.out.println("fecha: " + s);
    } else {
        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());         
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Mmmm lo hice asi pero igual el año sigue teniendo esos numeros despues de la coma con la diferencia que  los numeros despues de la coma se muestran una linea mas abajo, exactamente de esta forma:                                                                                        `f-->fecha:23/08/1996
---->35300.0`

Comment: claro, es lo que tu código original hace. Para que te aclares lo he impreso en líneas separadas en mi respuesta. ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: posteriormente quiero trabajar con el dato fecha pero leido como string para compararla con otra fecha que se entregue por parametro por el usuario

Comment: Ok, he agregado una clausula else para que imprima únicamente la fecha o el número, según sea el caso.

Comment: Ahi si funcionoooo! Muchas gracias te pasaste!!!!!

Comment: Es un placer ser de ayuda.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias. Lo recomendaré.